# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, lambda

How can I get this Lambda expression to work in Entity Framework?

Basically, if there is a `goalCyleId`, then look it up and get the end date of it.

```
.Select(x => new GoalDTO()
{
    GoalId = x.GoalId,
    Name = x.Name,
    DueDate = x.GoalCycleId == null ? null : _context.GoalCycles.Find(y => y.GoalCycleId == x.GoalCycleId).EndDate
})
```

I'm getting an error

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: using System.Data.Entity; Do you have this reference?

Comment: Looks as if you'd be better off with a [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Find` method of the DbSet class expects a primary key value as its parameter, but you are passing it a lambda expression. Use `FirstOrDefault`  instead.`_context.GoalCycles.FirstOrDefault(y => y.GoalCycleId == x.GoalCycleId).EndDate`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below query,

```
.Select(x => new GoalDTO() {
  GoalId = x.GoalId,
    Name = x.Name,
    DueDate = x.GoalCycleId == null ? null : _context.GoalCycles.FirstOrDefault(y => y.GoalCycleId == x.GoalCycleId).EndDate

})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your entities are set up with the navigation properties, you should just need something like:

```
.Select(x => new GoalDTO()
{
    GoalId = x.GoalId,
    Name = x.Name,
    DueDate = x.GoalCycle.EndDate
})
```

GoalCycleId on the Goal may be Null-able, so a GoalCycle navigation reference may be #null but when EF projects this down it would leave DueDate #null if there is no GoalCycle for that Goal, otherwise taking the End Date. However, that would trip a `NullReferenceException` if the `Select` is being done after the EF query is materialized. (I.e. premature `ToList()`)

It shouldn't complain with:

```
DueDate = x.GoalCycle?.EndDate
```